# Ubuntu won't start

Tags: 12.04, wubi

I've had Ubuntu installed, using WUBI, for some time now - a few months or so.
It's worked fine until now, allowing me to login, use it's features etc...
Two days ago, I turned on my computer and started Ubuntu. It loaded the GUI fine but just showed the loading screen and even after waiting 10 mins on this screen it still wouldn't show me the login page.

I am enthusiastic about web design and development and all of my work, along with my portfolio is stored in Ubuntu.

Cheers,
Tomas

EDIT:
I am using 12.04 LTS.

Comment: What did you do after the 10 mins?

Comment: After 10 mins Ubuntu shut itself down

Comment: Have you been able to get it to start up correctly since then?

Comment: By the loading screen, I presume you mean the purple screen that says Ubuntu with dots under it. When that first comes up, press `Esc`. This will show the messages behind it. Then **edit your question** to include as much of what you see as possible, especially error messages and whatever the last few lines say. (You may find it helpful to use the `<$>` tool in the editing toolbar to format these messages properly.)

Comment: @jimirings No. D:

Comment: @EliahKagan Esc method worked first time! Thank's so much!

Comment: @Tomas That made it boot??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's pretty bad,I think you should use a live CD and backup your data first as it contains all your work,Ubuntu install with Wubi do causes troubles sometimes, I think it will be better for you to do a fresh install and also get a seprate drive for your /home, such that  when due to any reason your system crashes, your data will still be safe.

Cheers,
Vinit